# CSS Nav Menu set effect on current item

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, nav, selected

I am developing a website of http://hcldesign.co.uk/ and have added a nav menu effect i found and integrated it onto my site using CSS.

The only problem is I can't figure out how to have the hover effect stay when i click the menu item and then the hover effect to also show on the current/active page/menu item. When i add the code i think it should be such as :Active this breaks the menu hover effect.

Current Code used for the menu is below

```
    `a:focus {
    color: #c9c9c9 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

     #menu-primary-menu {
     font-family: 'roboto', roboto, roboto;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#menu-primary-menu * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
#menu-primary-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0em 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-primary-menu a {
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu-primary-menu a:before,
#menu-primary-menu a:after {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  background-color: #3588dc;
  width: 0;
}
#menu-primary-menu a:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#menu-primary-menu a:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#menu-primary-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#menu-primary-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}


#menu-primary-menu a:hover:before,
#menu-primary-menu .current a:before,
#menu-primary-menu a:hover:after,
#menu-primary-menu .current a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

#menu-primary-menu a {
font-size: 14px;
margin: -10px
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Then edit your question to show us relevant code.

Comment: Current code added, sorry

Comment: Since you are not navigating to any different pages here, but are only using anchor links within the same page, the default WP mechanism that marks the current item of course doesn’t apply. You would have to first of all add some JavaScript that sets a class on the “current” element when you click it.

Comment: you can see i have managed to have the text change colour when clicked, would there be a way to have the two lines appear and stay when clicked?

Comment: _“you can see i have managed to have the text change colour when clicked”_ - yeah, but not really ... `:active` by definition only applies from when you press your mouse button down, until you release it again. Write a simple JavaScript that marks the current element with a class, and then modify your selectors that achieve this effect when the element gets hovered, so that this class triggers it as well.

Comment: Hi, Okay yep ive noticed that, I'm not too familiar with javascript but i will have a look. Do you have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Give each `<body id="mypage-one">` a id. You also have to give your `<nav>` item like `<li id="nav-page-one">` a id as well.

If you now going in your css that way, you'll have your effect you wish.

```
#mypage-one, #nav-page-one {
    background-color: #2a88bd;
}

#mypage-two, #nav-page-two {
    background-color: #2a88bd;
}
```

If your comma separated css selectors matches now, you'll get the `background-color` set to `#2a88bd` or how ever your hover effect is.

Hope you'll be successful.

Comment: Hi, Would it be possible buy having #nav-item-101 { background-color: #2a88bd; } ? As my nag items have just got random number assigned to them automatically and i don't know how these are changed in WordPress. This is a one page website with only a few other actual pages going to be added so would i need a page tag? and if so where can i find the page tag?

Comment: Hi, I have just added my current code, i need it to show the hover effect lines when the nav item is clicked

Comment: In you'r case you have to change the `#menu-primary-menu a` in that way i've worte before. Just use you'r development tool in you'r browser and scope it. You'll find amazing things!

Comment: sorry I'm not following

Answer (score 0):

I think when u using scrolling nav it's hard to do it as above. You can use jQuery to reach your goal. Look on this codepen how it works:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvXVXm

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.link').removeClass('active');
  $target = $(event.target);
  $target.addClass('active');
});
```

I think it will be helpful.

Regards

Comment: What classes would i need to use in the javascript from my code though?